# Copy database from linked MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL Servers:

1.MS SQL 2016 Express 2016

2.MS SQL 2014 Standard 2014

Recently I've a got task, where I need once per day at `00:00` to copy the whole database from `SQL Express 2016` to `SQL 2014 Standard Edition`.

These 2 servers are LINKED.

I cannot bck restore because it's not possible from lower to higher version also this is not possible neither with log shipping, can you please suggest any other option?

Thank you

BR

Comment: Do you just overwrite the copy every day?

Comment: if you really need to do this on a daily basis, you should really consider using same version. It solve a lot of unnecessary hassle and problem

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different options for completing this task.

1- Using Third Party Tools
2- By Generating Scripts

The easiest way to do such task is to use Third Party Tools. For more info use this link
'https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/restore-sql-server-database-backup-to-older-version-of-sql-server/'

You can also use export import wizard, but it is not feasible.